# Change settings (autoplay, effect, loop) of Swiper.JS settings when a class is toggled on the HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement, swiper.js

My swiper.JS works as intended. However a class can be added to the `html` tag when a link is toggled. When that happens and the class `retro` is added, I need to amend some of the settings such as `autoplay` `effect`, `loop` and introduce a scrollbar.

I've tried to achieve this using an `if` statement to amend only the setting that need updating - which doesn't work. Is this possible or would you need an entire new Swiper instance with all the previous setting defined as well?

Would I need to have two different (large) blocks of Swiper code with every parameter again in an if/else like so (but need to update on class change)?

```
if (html.classList.contains('retro')) {
  // Updated swiper.js script
} else {
  // Current swiper.js script
}
```

Or is there away just to change the relevant settings?

```js
/* FADE IN WHEN CONTENT LOADED */

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.body.className = "visible";
});




/* TOGGLE */

const html = document.querySelector('html');
const button = document.querySelector('.contrast__link');
button.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (html.classList.contains('dark-mode')) {
    html.classList.remove('dark-mode');
    html.classList.add('retro');
  } else if (html.classList.contains('retro')) {
    html.classList.remove('retro');
  } else {
    html.classList.add('dark-mode');
  }
});




/* CAROUSEL */

var caption = document.querySelector(".swiper-caption");

new Swiper(".swiper", {
  // Disable preloading of all images
  preloadImages: false,
  // Enable lazy loading
  lazy: true,
  effect: "fade",
  fadeEffect: {
    crossFade: true
  },
  loop: true,
  autoplay: {
    delay: 1200,
    disableOnInteraction: false,
    pauseOnMouseEnter: true
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
  },
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    type: "fraction"
  },
  on: {
    init: function() {
      updateCaptionText(this);
    },
    activeIndexChange: function() {
      updateCaptionText(this);
    }
  }
});

function updateCaptionText(slider) {
  caption.textContent = slider.slides[slider.activeIndex].dataset.caption;
}

/* The bit I only need set when the class `retro` is on the `html` tag. */

if (html.classList.contains('retro')) {
  Swiper('.swiper', {
    effect: 'slide',
    loop: false,
    autoplay: false,
    scrollbar: {
      el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
      draggable: true
    }
  });
}
```

```css
/* #GLOBAL */

body.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}

body.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.48s ease-out;
}

html {
  background: white;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  height: 100vh;
  height: var(--app-height);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

.dark-mode {
  background: yellow;
}

.retro {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}


/**
 * Base `body` styling.
 */

body {
  background-color: transparent;
  font-variant-ligatures: common-ligatures discretionary-ligatures historical-ligatures;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 100vh;
  height: var(--app-height);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

h1,
p {
  margin: 0 0 24px;
  padding: 0;
}


/* #HEAD (left column) */

.page-head {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 64px;
  padding: 0 24px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -64px;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  width: 100vh;
}

.site-logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 32px;
  order: 1;
  stroke: black;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  width: 32px;
  svg {
    overflow: visible;
  }
}

.contrast {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}


/* #GRID */

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.grid__item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 24px 24px 0;
  margin-left: 64px;
}

.gallery {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 24px 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery img {
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: top center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}


/**
 * Side-by-side view for wider devices.
 */

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  height: var(--app-height);
}


/**
 * Grid Cells.
 */

.grid__item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 48px 48px 0;
  margin-left: 48px;
  @media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

.gallery {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 24px 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery img {
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: top center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  @media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    width: auto;
  }
}


/**
 * Side-by-side view for wider devices.
 */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .grid {
    background-color: black;
    flex-direction: row;
    column-gap: 2px;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 48px;
  }
  .grid__item {
    background-color: white;
    transition: width 0.12s;
    width: 33.333333%;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  .gallery {
    padding-top: 24px;
  }
  .gallery img {
    height: 100%; // Was Auto to keep aspect-ratio
    max-height: 100%;
    //object-fit: initial;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .grid__item {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-height: 600px) {
  .grid {
    height: auto;
  }
  .grid__item {
    height: auto;
  }
}


/* #FOOTER (right column) */

.page-foot {
  margin-left: 64px;
  padding: 0 24px;
}

.swiper-pagination {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .page-foot {
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    height: 64px;
    padding: 0 24px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -64px;
    left: 0;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: top left;
    width: 100vh;
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: top right;
    p {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
  }
  .swiper-caption {
    flex: 1 1 0%;
  }
}


/* CURSOR */

* {
  //cursor: none !important;
}

body:hover {
  .cursor-trail {
    border-color: black;
  }
  .cursor span {
    background-color: black;
  }
}

.cursor {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.cursor span {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: background-color 0.12s ease-out, height 0.12s, opacity 0.12s, width 0.12s;
  position: fixed;
  width: 4px;
}

.cursor--click span {
  height: 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0 2px;
  width: 0;
}

.cursor-trail {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: fixed;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transition: border-color 0.12s ease-out, height 0.12s ease-out, margin 0.12s ease-out, opacity 0.12s ease-out, transform 0.24s cubic-bezier(0, 0.5, 1, 1), width 0.12s ease-out;
  width: 32px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.cursor-trail--hover {
  height: 4px;
  margin: 16px 0 0 16px;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 4px;
}


/* Prev */

.cursor-prev span,
.cursor-next span {
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 2px;
  transition: height 0.12s, opacity 0.12s, transform 0.12s, width 0.12s;
  transform-origin: center center;
  left: -16px;
  width: 32px;
  &:before,
  &:after {
    background: black;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    transform-origin: center left;
  }
  &:before {
    animation: cursor-prev 0.12s ease-in-out 0.32s forwards;
  }
  &:after {
    animation: cursor-next 0.12s ease-in-out 0.32s forwards;
  }
}

.cursor-next span {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

@keyframes cursor-prev {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
}

@keyframes cursor-next {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}


/* SWIPER */

.swiper {
  height: 100%; // Fits image in viewport
  position: relative;
  //overflow: hidden; // Removed which seems to help border getting cut off
  touch-action: pan-y;
  z-index: 1; // Fix of Webkit flickering
  -webkit-user-select: none; // Fixes issue in Safari when clicking carousel quickly, page is highlighted black.
}

.swiper-wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.swiper-slide {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%; // Added myself
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  transition: opacity 12ms ease-out !important;
  width: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide-active {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.swiper-button-prev,
.swiper-button-next {
  background: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  &:focus {
    outline: 0;
  }
}

.swiper-button-prev {
  left: 0;
}

.swiper-button-next {
  right: 0;
}

.swiper-pagination-current {
  margin-right: 4px;
}

.swiper-pagination-total {
  margin-left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/8.2.2/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<script>
  document.body.className = 'hidden';
</script>

<div class="cursor"><span></span></div>
<div class="cursor-trail"></div>

<div class="page-head" role="banner">
  <div class="site-logo">
    M
  </div>
  <p class="contrast"><a href="#" class="contrast__link"><span class="contrast__switch"></span><span class="contrast__label">Contrast</span></a></p>
</div>

<div class="grid" role="main">

  <div class="grid__item finder">
    <div class="hgroup title-bar">
      <h1 class="brand-name">Name of Page</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="grid__item gallery">

    <div class="swiper">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide" data-caption="1 Caption that is really, really, really, really long">
          <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/700/1000" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" data-caption="2 Caption that is really, really, really, really long">
          <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/700/1100" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" data-caption="3 Caption that is really, really, really, really long">
          <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/700/1200" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="swiper-button-prev" data-interaction="cursor-prev"></a>
      <a class="swiper-button-next" data-interaction="cursor-next"></a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="page-foot" role="contentinfo">
    <p class="swiper-caption">Caption that is really, really, really, really long...</p>
    <p class="swiper-pagination"></p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do to make the code simpler for yourself is user `Object.assign()` or `spread operator`.

It would look something like this:

You have your main settings for Swiper.JS

```
let defaultSwiperSettings = {  preloadImages: false, lazy: true, effect: "fade" };
```

Then whenever you want to change portion of default settings or add new ones you just have objects with changes you want. (The bit you need to change when some class is present)

```
let retroSpecificSwiperSettings = { effect: "jump", loop: false };
```

Now when it's time to set Swiper settings to retro class specific ones all you do is merge default with specific ones and update settings.

```
let mergedSettings = { ...defaultSwiperSettings, ...retroSpecificSwiperSettings };
```

Result of the merge will look like this

```
{ preloadImages: false, lazy: true, effect: "jump", loop: false }
```

Now you just need to pass `mergedSettings` to Swiper.JS

Also there is possibility of deep merge, but I don't think your use-case needs it.

Here is example of one possible implementation:

```js
/* FADE IN WHEN CONTENT LOADED */

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.body.className = "visible";
});

/* TOGGLE */

const html = document.querySelector('html');
const button = document.querySelector('.contrast__link');

let currentModeIndex = 0;
button.addEventListener('click', e => { e.preventDefault(); toggleMode()} );

function toggleMode() {
  const modes = ['light-mode', 'dark-mode', 'retro'];
  
  html.classList.remove(modes[currentModeIndex]);
  currentModeIndex = (currentModeIndex + 1) % modes.length;
  html.classList.add(modes[currentModeIndex]);
  setSwiperSettings(modes[currentModeIndex]);
}

/* CAROUSEL */

var caption = document.querySelector(".swiper-caption");

function updateCaptionText(slider) {
  caption.textContent = slider.slides[slider.activeIndex].dataset.caption;
}

const defaultSettings = {
  preloadImages: false,
  lazy: true,
  effect: "fade",
  fadeEffect: { crossFade: true },
  loop: true,
  autoplay: { delay: 1200, disableOnInteraction: false, pauseOnMouseEnter: true },
  navigation: { nextEl: ".swiper-button-next", prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev" },
  pagination: { el: ".swiper-pagination", type: "fraction" },
  on: { init: function() { updateCaptionText(this); }, activeIndexChange: function() { updateCaptionText(this); } }
};
  
const retroSpecificSettings = { effect: 'slide', loop: false, autoplay: false, scrollbar: { el: '.swiper-scrollbar', draggable: true } };

const swiperSettings = {
  default: defaultSettings,
  retro: { ...defaultSettings, ...retroSpecificSettings }
};

function setSwiperSettings(type) {
  swiper.destroy();
  swiper = new Swiper(".swiper", swiperSettings[type] || swiperSettings.default);
}

let swiper = new Swiper(".swiper", swiperSettings.default);
```

```css
/* #GLOBAL */

body.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}

body.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.48s ease-out;
}

html {
  background: white;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  height: 100vh;
  height: var(--app-height);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

.dark-mode {
  background: yellow;
}

.retro {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}


/**
 * Base `body` styling.
 */

body {
  background-color: transparent;
  font-variant-ligatures: common-ligatures discretionary-ligatures historical-ligatures;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 100vh;
  height: var(--app-height);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

h1,
p {
  margin: 0 0 24px;
  padding: 0;
}


/* #HEAD (left column) */

.page-head {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 64px;
  padding: 0 24px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -64px;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  width: 100vh;
}

.site-logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 32px;
  order: 1;
  stroke: black;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  width: 32px;
  svg {
    overflow: visible;
  }
}

.contrast {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}


/* #GRID */

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.grid__item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 24px 24px 0;
  margin-left: 64px;
}

.gallery {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 24px 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery img {
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: top center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}


/**
 * Side-by-side view for wider devices.
 */

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  height: var(--app-height);
}


/**
 * Grid Cells.
 */

.grid__item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 48px 48px 0;
  margin-left: 48px;
  @media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

.gallery {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 24px 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery img {
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: top center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  @media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    width: auto;
  }
}


/**
 * Side-by-side view for wider devices.
 */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .grid {
    background-color: black;
    flex-direction: row;
    column-gap: 2px;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 48px;
  }
  .grid__item {
    background-color: white;
    transition: width 0.12s;
    width: 33.333333%;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  .gallery {
    padding-top: 24px;
  }
  .gallery img {
    height: 100%; // Was Auto to keep aspect-ratio
    max-height: 100%;
    //object-fit: initial;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .grid__item {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-height: 600px) {
  .grid {
    height: auto;
  }
  .grid__item {
    height: auto;
  }
}


/* #FOOTER (right column) */

.page-foot {
  margin-left: 64px;
  padding: 0 24px;
}

.swiper-pagination {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .page-foot {
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    height: 64px;
    padding: 0 24px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -64px;
    left: 0;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: top left;
    width: 100vh;
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: top right;
    p {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
  }
  .swiper-caption {
    flex: 1 1 0%;
  }
}


/* CURSOR */

* {
  //cursor: none !important;
}

body:hover {
  .cursor-trail {
    border-color: black;
  }
  .cursor span {
    background-color: black;
  }
}

.cursor {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.cursor span {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: background-color 0.12s ease-out, height 0.12s, opacity 0.12s, width 0.12s;
  position: fixed;
  width: 4px;
}

.cursor--click span {
  height: 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0 2px;
  width: 0;
}

.cursor-trail {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: fixed;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transition: border-color 0.12s ease-out, height 0.12s ease-out, margin 0.12s ease-out, opacity 0.12s ease-out, transform 0.24s cubic-bezier(0, 0.5, 1, 1), width 0.12s ease-out;
  width: 32px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.cursor-trail--hover {
  height: 4px;
  margin: 16px 0 0 16px;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 4px;
}


/* Prev */

.cursor-prev span,
.cursor-next span {
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 2px;
  transition: height 0.12s, opacity 0.12s, transform 0.12s, width 0.12s;
  transform-origin: center center;
  left: -16px;
  width: 32px;
  &:before,
  &:after {
    background: black;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    transform-origin: center left;
  }
  &:before {
    animation: cursor-prev 0.12s ease-in-out 0.32s forwards;
  }
  &:after {
    animation: cursor-next 0.12s ease-in-out 0.32s forwards;
  }
}

.cursor-next span {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

@keyframes cursor-prev {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
}

@keyframes cursor-next {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}


/* SWIPER */

.swiper {
  height: 100%; // Fits image in viewport
  position: relative;
  //overflow: hidden; // Removed which seems to help border getting cut off
  touch-action: pan-y;
  z-index: 1; // Fix of Webkit flickering
  -webkit-user-select: none; // Fixes issue in Safari when clicking carousel quickly, page is highlighted black.
}

.swiper-wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.swiper-slide {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%; // Added myself
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  transition: opacity 12ms ease-out !important;
  width: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide-active {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.swiper-button-prev,
.swiper-button-next {
  background: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  &:focus {
    outline: 0;
  }
}

.swiper-button-prev {
  left: 0;
}

.swiper-button-next {
  right: 0;
}

.swiper-pagination-current {
  margin-right: 4px;
}

.swiper-pagination-total {
  margin-left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/8.2.2/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<script>
  document.body.className = 'hidden';
</script>

<div class="cursor"><span></span></div>
<div class="cursor-trail"></div>

<div class="page-head" role="banner">
  <div class="site-logo">
    M
  </div>
  <p class="contrast"><a href="#" class="contrast__link"><span class="contrast__switch"></span><span class="contrast__label">Contrast</span></a></p>
</div>

<div class="grid" role="main">

  <div class="grid__item finder">
    <div class="hgroup title-bar">
      <h1 class="brand-name">Name of Page</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="grid__item gallery">

    <div class="swiper">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide" data-caption="1 Caption that is really, really, really, really long">
          <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/700/1000" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" data-caption="2 Caption that is really, really, really, really long">
          <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/700/1100" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" data-caption="3 Caption that is really, really, really, really long">
          <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/700/1200" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="swiper-button-prev" data-interaction="cursor-prev"></a>
      <a class="swiper-button-next" data-interaction="cursor-next"></a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="page-foot" role="contentinfo">
    <p class="swiper-caption">Caption that is really, really, really, really long...</p>
    <p class="swiper-pagination"></p>
  </div>

</div>
```

It will just destroy previous slider and add new one for simplicity sake, but it's also possible to rewrite swiper.params (would make everything more complicated tho)

Comment: Hey, thanks for this! I'm 'out of office' but will try to take a look at how this works tomorrow. Will this work if a class is added to the page 'live'? So if the default settings are running, then `.retro` is added it'll update? Or it is just on page load and what class is set on load? Thanks again!

Comment: Added example code

Comment: Hey, sorry I've been away for a week so just getting caught up on this. Just trying to use it and I think there's an issue with `retro: { ...defaultSettings, ...retroSpecificSettings }`. Any ideas on what's up with that? Parsing error: Unexpected token ... (This location is where the parser gave up trying to understand your malformed JavaScript. The actual error may be somewhere else.)

Comment: Just wanted to follow up on this if possible - any idea on the above? that line seems to break my script so I can't get it working locally? Thanks again - the example looks great!

Comment: Could it be because I'm loading from an external JS file. So in my HTML doc it looks for `<script src="js/main.js"></script>`?

Comment: Actually my bad, I think I've got this working by just removing the `...`. The problem I've just noticed is when you toggle the image returns to the 1st one each time. I wouldn't mind this just on 'retro' but the first 2 states just change invert colours so it's better if they don't reset?

Comment: Regarding to '...' not working it's a standard javascript feature since ES2015 and it is called 'spread operator'. It might be that your javascript compiler or bundler is really old or you might be using it wrong.

Comment: I actually managed to fix that bit! It was just because I'm loading JS from a separate file. Removing the `...` got it working like your example :)

Comment: Regarding it jumping back to first image. I am not familiar with this slider but I would look for a way in documentation to update slider settings on the fly, instead of completely destroying slider and creating new one. It might be not possible in which case best solution would be to ask slider on which slide it currently is before destroying it and after recreating it setting the current slide manually.